# Force Windows 10 to one mail profile regardless of user

Tags: windows-10, outlook

As I understand it, Windows 10 Outlook mail profiles are in the user data/hive. Is there a way to force a machine to use one single mail profile regardless of the domain user logged in? One service account, never their personal accounts?

Comment: Not an end user question I'm asking how to administer something for a whole department.

Answer (score 0):

We don't see much your goal there, but yes a generic account for that computer might be the solution.

The problem like @djdomi stated is autodiscover will get the account setting for the user that login.

The second solution would be to deleguate the mailbox you want to share to all user that go to that computer.

The goal is if your user sit to that computer, do you really want them to not use their personnal email ? it,s lost produtivity there IMO, so using a deleguated mailbox would make them available that second mailbox you want them to use.

Comment: The computer in question is a shared one-function workstation that they log into with their personal domain accounts, but it is not their normal workstation. They RDP to it for an application.